# How to convert doctrine entity to array if I have objects in result set already?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, jms-serializer

I am fetching entities using iterate and doing updating its values. I have huge data set so inserting it using doctrine takes lot of time.

I want to write doctrine entities to csv file and load entire huge data set using mysql "LOAD DATA INFILE".

Is there any way to just write doctrine objects as csv values in file or atleast convert to array which I can write to csv ?

I tried JMSSerialiser but it doesn't output to array.

Comment: Are you trying to load some static data or dummy entities? If yes, have a look at [Doctrine Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

Comment: I have mentioned  in question that I am fetching entities using iterate and updating its values. I am doing some processing on them and trying to insert them in other table